# Why can't I call Optional methods on an optional-chained type?

Tags: swift

Consider the following example where `foo` is explicitly defined as optional:

```swift
let foo: Int? = 10
let bar = foo.map { $0 * 2 }
```

This compiles and works as expected. Now consider a subsequent example using optional chaining:

```
let foo: [Int]? = [0, 1, 2]
let bar = foo?.count.map { $0 * 2 }
```

This fails to compile with the following message:

```
error: value of type 'Int' has no member 'map'
```

Why does the compiler see `foo?.count` as an `Int` and not an `Int?`? This defies the [Swift Language Book](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/OptionalChaining.html):

> To reflect the fact that optional chaining can be called on a nil value, the result of an optional chaining call is always an optional value, even if the property, method, or subscript you are querying returns a non-optional value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an operator precedence issue. You need to add parentheses to change the order:

```
let bar = (foo?.count).map { $0 * 2 }
```

Consider the case of a Collection like String rather than an Int:

```
let foo: String? = "ABC"
let bar = foo?.uppercased().map(\.isLowercase) // [false, false, false]
```

In this case, it's sensible that the `.map` applies to the String rather than to the Optional. If the precedence were the other way, then you'd need a `?.` at every step (or a lot of parentheses :D)

Comment: This is incorrect consider trying: let i = 20;  i.map({$0 * 1}); This operation will cause an error in swift not because of any optional precedence, but because int cannot perform map.

Comment: The book refers to the result not the unwrapping of an optional for use, in fact an optional cannot be used with any type call without being unwrapped first. It would be the same as removing the question mark to call count on optional type. This does not work in swift.

Comment: @SeaSpell Optional is an enum, and it has its own methods. This question is about the `.map` method of Optional (which exists), not Int. For example, `[1].first.map { $0 * 2 }` is valid (and useful) Swift. Note the lack of any `?` (and a `?` would be invalid). Its return type would be `Int?`.

Comment: There are a few pieces of magic syntax around Optional (particularly `?.` and Optional promotion), but Optional itself is not magical. It's just a completely standard enum, written in Swift: https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/main/stdlib/public/core/Optional.swift  Note the description "You must unwrap the value of an `Optional` instance before you can use it **in many contexts.**" And that's true. But not **all** contexts.

Comment: Ok so I agree with you that optional can call map, optional is indeed an enum, and it does define the method map on optional type.  My understanding of the question is why the compiler error. Foo is an optional array of Int, count is a var of  Array : RandomAccessCollection, MutableCollection , not an optional. When the if foo is nil, count cannot be called. If it is not nil count is called on [Int] not on optional.

Comment: In your example you provide an optional Int using precedence, but does not explain the error error: value of type 'Int' has no member 'map' or the books interpretation. I agree with you that you can cause an optional value and map that, maybe I'm just misunderstood the question, I do think its an important distinction

Comment: I have to add one more thing, In your example (foo?.count) returns an optional as described by the book because the result type of the chain requires an optional result. The distinction must be made however that as optional in swift is a first class type you are actually trying to call .count on the wrapped value not the optional. When .count is called(if it is called) it is not called on type optional, but rather on the wrapped value. I think that is important to understand.

Comment: The compiler error is because `foo?.count.map{...}` is equivalent to `foo.flatMap({ $0.count.map{...})`. In that context, `$0` is unambiguously Int, $0.count is Int, and there is no Int.map. When this is converted to `(foo?.count).map{...}`, that is equivalent to `foo.flatMap({ $0.count }).map { ... }`. Again, in that context, $0 is Int and $0.count is Int. The flatMap returns `Optional<Int>`, and `Optional<Int>.map` exists. In this example the choice of what method to try to call is unambiguous, and unrelated to the expected return type (there are no overloads).

Comment: (foo?.count) returns an optional Int. foo.flatMap($0.count) returns an array of Int not optionals. foo is an Optional<Array<Int>>. foo.flatMap({ $0.count.map{$0} }) can not work because again you are trying to call map on type Int.

Answer (score 0):

The type of count unwraps to Int if available. Int does not implement the function map. Optional chaining simply fails when it finds nil. The compiler is trying to tell you if it does not fail the operation map cannot happen. The result is bar which is indeed an optional, because if the operation fails( because something unwraps to nil) the entire chain must return nil.